# How to concatenate two variable values and use in if condition

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to append the relative path of a file to a root path to get the complete path of the file. The same file, i am trying to check if exists , then trying to rename it to todays date . I am using the below code. While exhoing the concatenated values in out1.txt i am getting correct values. But  in if condition ,I am getting syntax error on concatenating the values of two variables here. I think i am doing something wrong Can anyone please help . Thanks a lot.

```
echo on


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set rootPath=C:\Endeca




rem copying to index 
set indexTarget=%rootPath%
set IndexFilePath=Tiffany\ENI\Endeca
set MDEXFilePath=Tiffany\ENE\Endeca

cd %IndexFilePath%
set "parentfolder=%CD%"
for /r . %%g in (*.*) do (
  set "completepath=%%g"
  set relativePath=!completepath:%parentfolder%=!  
  echo !rootPath!!relativePath! >> out1.txt
  if exist !rootPath!!relativePath! 
 for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do rename "!%rootPath%%relativePath%!" %rootPath%%relativePath%.%%b-%%c-%%d

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely untested rewrite of your code, based upon my understanding of what you're trying to do.

The main issue I could see with it was that your `if` condition did not use parentheses to isolate the command(s) specific to it.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelaydExpansion
Set "rootPath=C:\Endeca"
Set "dStamp="
For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined dStamp Set "dStamp=%%A-%%B-%%C"
Rem Copying to index 
Set "indexTarget=%rootPath%"
Set "IndexFilePath=Tiffany\ENI\Endeca"
Set "MDEXFilePath=Tiffany\ENE\Endeca"
CD "%IndexFilePath%"
Set "parentfolder=%CD%"
For /R %%A In (*) Do (
    Set "completepath=%%~nA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "relativePath=!completepath:%parentfolder%=!"
    (Echo %rootPath%!relativePath!%%~xA)>>"out1.txt"
    If Exist "%rootPath%!relativePath!%%~xA" (
        Ren "%rootPath%!relativePath!%%~xA" "%rootPath%!relativePath!.%dStamp%%%~xA"
    )
    EndLocal
)
```

You'll note that I have moved the [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), designed to get the date string, from its nested position to nearer the start of your code. I have assumed that this was supposed to be in `YYYY-mm-DD` format, you'll need to adjust `%%A-%%B-%%C` on line `6` if that assumption was incorrect.